# How can I get my GridView to take up all the width available to it within its column?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

In my page I've got a GridView which inhabits the middle (and largest) of three columns (taking up half (6/12ths) of the page). It displays as if it has margin and/or padding added to its left and right sides, though. I want it to expand outward to fill all available space.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="col-6">
. . .
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieTitle" HeaderText="MovieTitle" SortExpression="MovieTitle" />
        . . .
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Minutes" HeaderText="Minutes" SortExpression="Minutes" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

...and here's how it looks:

[image]

(BTW, the data is "fake," not what would actually be returned if the user selected the "Find" button)

You can, of course, set the width to an absolute value, but I don't see a way to set it to a relative value (such as, 100% of the column width).

I tried to set it to the width of the column, too, but that property is not exposed for me to do that. IOW, I made the div a code-behindable element by giving it an Id and adding "runat server":

```
<div ID="col6" runat="server" class="col-6">
```

...and then tried in the code-behind to do this:

```
GridView1.Width = col6.Width;
```

...but col6 has no such public property.

Comment: `class="col-6"` probably has some padding. You can override it but it will affect everything. You will probably have to do this with some CSS hacks, like `width: 102%` (which will probably screw other things up, if it works at all), or maybe `margin-left: -10px`. Just some ideas. Hard to fix without a working example. Also, it looks fine the way it is.

Comment: You can also set class `px-0 mx-0` next to your `col-6` that will overwrite col-6 padding /  margin. But in that case you will need to set padding / margin on some child if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because bootstrap apply by default a padding on all its column. As you can see in below code:

```
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

This padding is here to compensate the margin that is set by bootstrap in row, as you can see in the below code:

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

So f you dont want this to happen, I recommand you to always apply `mx-0`when you have a row and `px-0` when you have a `col`

This class will be like:

```
mx-0{
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
px-0{
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

So just apply `row mx-0` and `col-6 px-0` Then you will probabaly need to adjust some of your div in col-6 to get a bit space.